# Reading only numbers from a file, from a specific line

Tags: c++, arrays, ifstream

I am trying to read from a data file that contains a header which is 4 lines, and also has a list of numbers that I will be storing into a 2d int array

for example

header

header

header

header

int

int

int

int

......

I need to somehow skip these header lines which contain text and only use the int lines and store them into the aforementioned 2d array. When I open the file and search through it, it doesn't store any values at all because of the text at the very start. I've tried multiple if statements and other things to get around this, but has worked so far.

```
int main()
{

    ifstream imageFile;
    imageFile.open("myfile");

    if (!imageFile.is_open())
    {
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int test2[16][16];
    int word;
    imageFile >> word;

    while (imageFile.good())
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
            {

                test2[i][j] = word;
                imageFile >> word;

            }
        }

}
```

Comment: getline, getline, getline, getline, read the rest.

Comment: Or always read strings, check the format, then skip or format to the data type you need (if number of header lines varies).

Comment: You have two tasks here. 1) throw away the first four lines, and 2) read in the integers. You can't do step 2 until you've done step 1. Do step 1.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, you need to first read the headers - here I just store the headers in a `trash` variable which is a string that's being overwritten every time I store new header:

```
std::string trash;
for (int i =0; i < 4; i++)
    std::getline(imageFile, trash);
```

This part goes after you check if file opened correctly and will be directly followed by your original code where you declare the 2D array and read the integers.

As it was also said in the comments you need `std::getline` that reads every header line as a whole and not a word at a time which was the first version of my answer (`imageFile >> trash;`).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this just by regex and patterns (Modify code for 2d array this is just example for how you can extract numbers from file or string):

```
std::string ss;

ifstream myReadFile;
myReadFile.open("foo.txt");
char output[100];
if (myReadFile.is_open()) {
    while (!myReadFile.eof()) {

        myReadFile >> output;
        ss.append(output);
        ss.append("\n");

    }
}
myReadFile.close();

std::regex rx(R"((?:^|\s)([+-]?[[:digit:]]+(?:\.[[:digit:]]+)?)(?=$|\s))"); // Declare the regex with a raw string literal
std::smatch m;
std::string str = ss;
while (regex_search(str, m, rx)) {
    std::cout << "Number found: " << m[1] << std::endl; // Get Captured Group 1 text
    str = m.suffix().str(); // Proceed to the next match
}
```

Output:

```
Number found: 612
Number found: 551
Number found: 14124
```